# have text surrounded by big quote marks

Tags: html, css

I want paragraphs to be surrounded by big quotes.
I tried multiple things but I keep messing with my line-height as can be seen in this image:

[image]

What is a descent way to do this?

(And as a extra, is there a cool closing version for this quote? >> 69)

```
<p><span>&#8223</span><a href="#">Foobar</a><br />Foobar<br />Foobar<span>&#8223</span></p>
<p><span>&#8223</span><a href="#">Foobar</a><span>&#8223</span></p>
<p><span>&#8223</span><a href="#">Foobar</a><span>&#8223</span></p>

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
}

span {
    font-size: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

p {
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: can you add a picture how it should look?

Comment: Damn, it was to hard to search google for a nice solution. Using `:before`and `:after` is the elegant way. Here's a tut http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/simple-and-nice-blockquote-styling/

Comment: http://willmoyer.tumblr.com/post/1580362250/css-pseudo-element-blockquotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/simple-and-nice-blockquote-styling/

is an excellent article on what you need.

[**This Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhapranavs/o5xoxx03/1/) uses the above concept to do that

CSS

```
blockquote {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 1.5em 10px;
    padding: 0.5em 10px;
    quotes:"\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
    padding: 30px;
    position:relative;
}
blockquote:before {
    position:absolute;
    color: #ccc;
    content: open-quote;
    font-size: 4em;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
blockquote:after {
    position:absolute;
    color: #ccc;
    content: close-quote;
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<blockquote>
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac 
turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor 
sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies 
mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1):

The blockquote displays in standards-compliant browsers with the "big quotes before" effect, and in IE with a thick left border and a light grey background.
Unlike other blockquote techniques, this style does not require a nested block-level element (like p). As such, it turns a paragraph into an inline-styled element to keep the content from dropping below the quote.

**CSS**

```
blockquote {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}
blockquote:before {
  color: #ccc;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
blockquote p {
  display: inline;
}
```

**JSFiddle example** - http://jsfiddle.net/xgku06ho/

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
p:before {
 content: '"';
}

p:after {
 content: '"';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use psudo to fix

```
p {
  line-height: 10px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}
p:before {
  color: #ccc;
  content: '';
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/r9b4ptsr/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would use images with css like that if you can't have the result you want with only css.Change the open and close images as you like: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/funeygf0/

```css
blockquote.style3 {
  font: 18px/30px normal Tahoma, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 22px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-image: url(http://css-tricks.com/examples/Blockquotes/images/openquote3.gif);
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: 65px;
}
blockquote.style3 span {
  display: block;
  background-image: url(http://css-tricks.com/examples/Blockquotes/images/closequote3.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="style3"><span>Ut nonummy habent soluta claritas veniam. Typi nunc soluta hendrerit mutationem sollemnes. Quis lius dolore et insitam vel. Aliquip consequat futurum claram ut mazim. Facilisi accumsan dolore ii imperdiet consequat. Claritatem aliquip quod putamus vulputate iusto. Doming minim typi zzril lius usus. In clari mutationem autem non sit. Qui augue mirum dynamicus gothica ut. Demonstraverunt  soluta sequitur autem.</span>
</blockquote>
```

Result:
[image]